# Suppressing namespace prefix in XML file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xml-namespaces

**Input File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="json" ContentType=""/>
    <Override PartName="/Version" ContentType=""/>
</Types>
```

**Output That I get:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<xmlns:Types xmlns:xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <xmlns:Default Extension="json" ContentType=""/>
    <xmlns:Override PartName="/Version" ContentType=""/>
    <xmlns:Default Extension="png" ContentType=""/>
</xmlns:Types>
```

**Required Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="json" ContentType=""/>
    <Override PartName="/Version" ContentType=""/>
    <Default Extension="png" ContentType=""/>
</Types>
```

I added the default tag that has Extension attribute with "png" as value using the below lines. On adding the above tag namespace gets added to each tag. I am new in Python, XML handling. I have tried this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def formatxml():
    dest="input.xml"
    tree = ET.parse(dest)
    root = tree.getroot()
    ET.register_namespace('xmlns',"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types")
    child=ET.SubElement(root,"{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content- types}Default")
    child.set('Extension',"png")
    child.set('ContentType',"")
    tree.write(dest,xml_declaration=True,encoding='utf-8',method="xml")
```

Comment: Why not to use XSLT for such task?

Comment: Use lxml instead of elementttree, if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`register_namespace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace) sets the prefix to be used when serializing the XML. Since you don't want any prefix, use an empty string.

All you need to do is to change

```
ET.register_namespace('xmlns',"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types")`
```

to

```
ET.register_namespace('',"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use XSLT for the task.

The XSLT is following so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="json" ContentType=""/>
    <Override PartName="/Version" ContentType=""/>
</Types>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types" exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:Override">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <Default Extension="png" ContentType=""/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
  <Default Extension="json" ContentType=""/>
  <Override PartName="/Version" ContentType=""/>
  <Default Extension="png" ContentType=""/>
</Types>
```