# Adding an attribute to every XML element in an XLIFF file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, xliff

I want to add **xml:space="preserve"** to every  element in Xliff files like this one:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">

<file datatype="plaintext" source-language="en-US" target-language="de-DE" date="2023-01-19T14:30:55Z" xml:space="preserve">
<body>

<trans-unit size-unit="char" approved="no" maxwidth="70" id="TITLE">
    <source>Add test scripts to execution queue</source>
    <target state="translated">Testskripte zur Ausführungs-Queue hinzufügen</target>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit size-unit="char" approved="no">
    <source>Dynamic ID</source>
    <target state="translated">Dynamic-ID</target>
</trans-unit>
<trans-unit size-unit="char" approved="no" maxwidth="132">
    <source>Identification</source>
    <target state="translated">Identifikation</target>
</trans-unit>

</body>
</file>
</xliff>
```

The Python script I have looks like this, but also adds **ns0:** to the beginning of each element in the XML file.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("input.xlf")
root = tree.getroot()

for trans_unit in root.iter("{urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2}trans-unit"):
    trans_unit.attrib["{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}space"] = "preserve"

tree.write("output.xlf")
```

Why does that happen and can someone help to improve the script?

Comment: Use the `register_namespace()` function. In your case it would be `ET.register_namespace("", "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2")`. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/68470618/407651

Answer (score 0):

OK, adding `ET.register_namespace("", "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2")`
and then also `encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)` to the `tree.write` statement did the trick.
Thanks, @[mzjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407651/mzjn)!